# How can I handle -r=<pattern> with Perl's Getopt::Long?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I am parsing command line options in Perl using [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Getopt::Long). I am forced to use prefix `-` (one dash) for short commands (`-s`) and `--` (double dash) for long commands (e.g., `--input=file`).

My problem is that there is one special option (`-r=<pattern>`) so it is long option for its requirement for argument, but it has to have one dash (`-`) prefix not double dash (`--`) like other long options. Is possible to setup [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Getopt::Long) to accept these?

Comment: Ouch. It really can't be changed to `-r arg` or `--r=arg` or anything at this point? Not only is it making work for you, seems like it's confusing to the user to have an option breaking the usual convention.

Comment: P.S. I'm not trying to avoid giving you an answer - I know you're probably already aware of what I said. (Also I don't think there is an answer within Getopt::Long)

Comment: The trick is to make arguments look like what people expect from other programs. It's when you want a new syntax that things get weird and you have to do a lot of work to parse them.

Answer (score 6):

By default, [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) interchangeably accepts either single (-) or double dash (--). So, you can just use `--r=foo`.  Do you get any error when you try that?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
my $input = 2;
my $s = 0;
my $r = 3;
GetOptions(
    'input=s' => \$input,
    's'       => \$s,
    'r=s'     => \$r,
);
print "input=$input\n";
print "s=$s\n";
print "r=$r\n";
```

These sample command lines produce the same results:

```
my_program.pl --r=5
my_program.pl --r 5
my_program.pl  -r=5
my_program.pl  -r 5

input=2
s=0
r=5
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you setting "bundling" on?

If so, you can disable bundling (but then, you won't be able to do things like use `myprog -abc` instead of `myprog -a -b -c`).

Otherwise, the only thing that comes to mind right now is to use [Argument Callback](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Argument-callback) (`<>`) and manually parse that option.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my $pattern;

GetOptions('r=s' => \$pattern);

print $pattern, "\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> zz -r=/test/
/test/
C:\Temp> zz -r /test/
/test/
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think what he describes might be due to bundling being on?

Comment: @DVK That is likely the case. I did not think of that.